# Ubuntu - upgrade distribution to specific release

Tags: ubuntu

How do I upgrade an older version of Ubuntu Server (Jaunty, for example) to a specific later version (Lucid, for example) using the command line?

I'm concerned that dist-upgrade is going to update to the latest, which is not LTS

clarification:

- has to be command line
- our internal mirror has removed the Jaunty images
- tried editing /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades to use only LTS versions, but it hangs. (trying to reach an outside server?)

Update:
 It seems Jaunty to Lucid is not possible (directly) [ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47807/how-do-i-upgrade-from-9-04-to-10-04-2), but my question was still for the more general case

Answer (score 5):

`dist-upgrade` does not technically perform a release upgrade. You're looking for the `do-release-upgrade` command. If you've got `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` set to `prompt=LTS` and the packages are available on your mirror it should work. If not, I would suggest verifying the packages on the mirror next.

Comment: In /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades (12.04) it reads "# normal ... the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running release." and a similar behavior is described for prompt=lts: "will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after the currently-running one". So both should work according to this however when I run `do-release-upgrade` it tries to jump all the way up to 14.04 LTS, the current latest release :(