# do-release-upgrade skipped a version - how to specify a release?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ubuntu-12.10, upgrade

I have a experienced a slightly odd behaviuour in the Ubuntu upgrade utility and am lefting wanting to know. Also I am trying to replicate an environment as closely as possible, and upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04 may be relevant.

I downloaded 12.10.4 server, installed it as close to "defaults" as possible, and ran `do-release-upgrade` -- this bumped me straight up to 13.10, without first trying to move me to 13.04

How do I define a specific release for this process? (id est, where are the configs for do-release-upgrade)

I've only found [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/302027/ubuntu-upgrade-distribution-to-specific-release) to be vaguely relevant but does not answer my question...

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade to 13.04? It's already end-of-life, so it's probably not the best idea.

Comment: To replicate a "production" environment. Yes maybe that env should also be upgraded, but baby steps. First I'm trying to replicate my environment as it is, so that I can test my procedures before hosing my live env.

Answer (score 1):

the file is in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

i assume this happens because 13.04 is already end-of-life and therefor the next supported version is 13.10 though not 100% sure, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_end_of_life)

change

> prompt=normal

or try

> do-release-upgrade -d

after the config change.

This seems to be the official solution to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04

Source: [Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RaringUpgrades)

check though which version you get

for completion to know which version is LTS and which is not:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin)
Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)
Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)
Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)
```

Source: [Wikipedia List of Ubuntu Versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_end_of_life)

Comment: For some reason the VPS provider was still offering 12.10 a few weeks ago when I created a new account (and I selected it, thinking I was getting 12.04). So I upgraded to 13.04 thinking "18 months support" mixing my distro EOL offerings up...

Long story short I did the 12.10->13.04 upgrade when 13.04 was already out of date (just a couple of weeks ago) so I doubt that's the explanation.

It may be that I'll simply have to do a backup of everything, ask the provider to reinitialize my host to a vanilla 14.04 and hope everything is resolved that way..

Thanks though!